# Extraer texto de una cadena en R

Tags: r, string, regex

Tengo una base de la que debo extraer parte del texto, el nombre de la empresa.

Va un ejemplo:

```
995 945 Disprofa 741 593 63 56 302 292 351 Servicios  
996 0 Terminal Puerto garin 740 Terminal  
997 783 Las Las 740 871 -73 -51 142 203 885 969 450 Activ. de edición
```

Estuve probando con expresiones regulares en R:

```
str2 <- 995 945*Disprofa 741 593 63 56 302 292 351 Servicios
str3 <- strsplit(str2, "[0-9][\\s][0-9][\\s]", perl = TRUE) # Divide cadenas   
str3 <- as.character(str3) 
str4 <- strsplit(str3, "[\\s][0-9]", perl = TRUE)
```

Con esto logro cortarlo, pero necesito especificamente extraer el texto y aplicarlo a todo un data frame.

A alguien se le ocurre una solución?

Comment: No se R pero esta expresión regular te encuentra todos los textos que colocaste en tu ejemplo: `( ?[A-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüÜ\.]+)` Por ejemplo encontrara `Disprofa`, `Servicios`, `Terminal Puerto garin` y `Terminal`, etc. Tal vez puedas separarlo por primera ocurrencia y segunda ocurrencia. Hay lenguajes que devuelven un arreglo con las ocurrencias en estos casos. No se si eso se pueda en R. Por cierto tambien encontre esta regex que te devuelve todos los segundos textos: `[\D]* *$` Devolvera `Servicios`, `Terminal` y `Activ. de edición`

Comment: Las palabras separadas por números deben considerarse como nombres separados? Por ejemplo, para tu primer ejemplo: `995 945 Disprofa 741 593 63 56 302 292 351 Servicios` debería encontrar `Disprofa` y además `Servicios` o bastaría con `Disprofa Servicios`

Comment: Alcanza y sobre con que encuentre la primera

Comment: Me parece que no tienes forma de resolverlo completamente, el comienzo del nombre de la empresa es sencillo de encontrar, pero.. ¿el final?. Podríamos decir hasta el próximo número que aparezca, pero ¿qué pasa con las empresas que tienen números dentro de su nombre? estaríamos cortando de mas.

Comment: @JuanTeje, alcanza con la primera (`disprofa` + `servicios`). Pero: ¿La segunda sería aceptable también? (`Disprofa servicios` (todo junto))

Comment: Lo ideal seria extraer solo el nombre de la empresa, pero si que es aceptable

Comment: Puedes utilizar: `[^\s0-9][^0-9\-]{2,}[^\s0-9]` que devuelve "Disprofa",  "Servicios", "Terminal Puerto garin",  "Terminal" y "Activ. de edición". Espero que esto es lo que buscabas.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con lo siguiente para quedarte con la primera palabra o palabras entre números:

```
texto <- '995 945 Paraguas David e hijos 741 593 63 56 302 292 351 Servicios 123 123'

texto <- sub("^[\\d\\s]+(\\w+(?:\\s+(?!\\d+\\s)\\w+)+)[\\s\\S]*", "\\1", texto, perl = TRUE)

print(texto)
```

Resultado:

"Paraguas David e hijos"

Tienes una demo **[aquí](https://rextester.com/WANVJV45465)**

Answer (score 1):

Puedes emplear expresiones regulares con la librería *stringr*. Prueba lo siguiente:

1. Emplea *str_extract_all()* para extraer una lista de todas las palabras que contengan coincidencias con el patrón *[:alpha:]+* Este patrón indica que seleccione todos los caracteres alfabéticos de la cadena.
2. *str_extract_all()* nos devolverá una lista con todos las palabras que encuentre. Aplicamos *unlist()* para lo convierta a vector.
3. Finalmente aplicamos *paste(collapse = ' ')* para que nos convierta ese vector en una cadena de texto que contenga todas las palabras que necesitamos. El código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
library(tidyverse)

'995 945 Disprofa 741 593 63 56 302 292 351 Servicios  ' %>% 
str_extract_all('[:alpha:]+') %>% 
unlist() %>% 
paste(collapse = ' ')
```